# Netbeans only slow when copying and pasting?

Tags: netbeans

My Netbeans has been insanely fast for over 2 years, until this morning. Something strange, however, is now happening. Every time i press "copy and paste" ... so CTRL-C, it goes slow. This is what I see:

[image: Netbeans bar slow]

So, the moment I press CTRL-C, that shows in the bottom, my entire machines goes into super slow mode, and then 5 seconds later it stops.

I've considered maybe there's a keylogger on my machine, but can't find anything. And it's only slow when I copy and paste from Netbeans, nothing else. Maybe Netbeans is sending data out some other way?

Any ideas why Netbeans would just go slow like this?

*UPDATE*

- I only have one project open
- I've disabled the git and subversion plugins
- I am working on a Laravel project
- It's slow when I copy from a VIEW or when I copy from a CONTROLLER (I know css files often go a bit slow because of Parsing, so I figured mentioning this is probably worthwhile)

Comment: Which netbeans u using i mean what version?

Comment: Version 8. But the answer I gave solved my problem.

Comment: okey no prob. but ya was facing same prob because of prasence of unwanted Plugin.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I followed the advice at the end of this article: [here](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=218370) and uninstalled "BlueStacks". Problem solved.

**UPDATE**
Just in case the article gets deleted, here is the advice the user gives on that page:

> I meet the same problem. When I copy a word in the IDE, the IDE does not response until 2 or 3 seconds. I did not confront this problem until few days ago. I try to use the latest netbeans and the latest jdk, but that does not work. Then I find someone said http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5078787 is the problem. And the problem is somewhat about the COM in windows. So I try to install the netbeans to another Win7 PC, and the problem is gone. In that case, I guess the problem is not the netbeans, but some other application in windows. Later I uninstall some of the application I just installed few days ago. And the IDE works  right now. The applications I uninstalled is "imc studio" "imc license manager" and "blueStacks" an android simulator. I guess these application may have influence to the COM of Win7. Hope my solution will help to this bug.

Comment: Amazing. What a find! Solved the problem for me...!

Comment: Hello, in my case it was related to "Splunk Enterprise"

Answer (score 3):

You can also just stop the BlueStacks Agent process from Task Manager while you're using NetBeans.